# Microsoft Graph API send email using Access Token of Enterprise Application

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on python code to send an email from Outlook using Microsoft Graph API. For this, I have created an Enterprise Application in my Azure Active Directory Tenant. I have granted admin consent for the tenant to the application on Mail.Send permission. I'm able to get the access token for Graph API with the help of this application, but I'm not able to send the mail. Can anyone please help me to understand, what is the issue with my code?

Python Code:

```
from requests import post


CLIENT_SECRET_VALUE = 'CLIENT_SECRET_VALUE'
TENANT_ID = 'TENANT_ID'
CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID'

LOGIN_URI = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token'

headers = {
    'Host': 'login.microsoftonline.com',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}


body = {
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET_VALUE,
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'tenant': TENANT_ID
}


response = post(url=LOGIN_URI, headers=headers, data=body)
response.raise_for_status()
response_body = response.json()

authorization_token = f"{response_body['token_type']} {response_body['access_token']}"

print(authorization_token)

email_header = {
    'Authorization': authorization_token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

message = {
    'body': {
        'content': 'Outlook Mail Testing Demo',
        'contentType': 'Text'
    },
    'sender': {
        'emailAddress': {
            'address': 'email.address.of.shared.mailbox@active-directory-tenant.tld',
            'name': 'Name of Shared Mailbox'
        }
    },
    'subject': 'Testing email',
    'toRecipients': [
        {
            'emailAddress': {
                'address': 'temprorary.email.address@another-domain.tld',
                'name': 'Name of person to whom email belongs'
            }
        }
    ]
}

email_body = {
    'message': message
}


email_send_response = post(url='https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/sendMail', headers=email_header, data=email_body)
email_send_response.raise_for_status()
```

[N.B.: CLIENT_SECRET_VALUE is getting generated by the enterprise application. TENANT_ID & CLIENT_ID are the tenant and client ids assigned to the application]

On running the code, I'm getting an error:

```
400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/sendMail
```

Comment: I can see that the API call you are doing is not correct. Try using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userid/sendMail`. We use `me` only when you login as user and get the token. As you are using client credential flow, you should give users/userid/sendMail Or users/userprincipalname/sendmail

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma I really appreciate your reply. I have a mailbox whose user principal name is `python-demo@sam-solutions.in`, using this mailbox, I'm trying to send the email, so I have replaced the endpoint to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/python-demo@sam-solutions.in/sendMail` but still I'm getting same(400 Client Error) error

Comment: Try using the id of the user. You can get it from AzueAD -> Users -> UPN

Comment: I have tried to use object id of the user in the form `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/6c2509c7-bc20-40ab-9d88-10df80aa678c/sendMail`, but still I'm getting same issue

Comment: I am not an expert in python but I guess now it is the issue with the body of the request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems in your code. As I specified the first issue in comments that the URL should be as below as you are using client credential flow.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid/UPN}/sendMail
```

The second problem I have identified after a long research in python is that the body which you are sening with the API call is not in the format of json. So I have used `import json` and method `json.dumps` and tested it. Then it worked.

***Code:***

```
from requests import post
import json

CLIENT_SECRET_VALUE = 'aX27Q~insds3EvI4z8otRNGHRcCgdjeFOTSpCLPZ'
TENANT_ID = '363147dc-b3be-41a7-af56-f67894ef5a7'
CLIENT_ID = 'e61195e5-7955-4558-9126-37f6cf372d45'

LOGIN_URI = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token'

headers = {
    'Host': 'login.microsoftonline.com',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}


body = {
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET_VALUE,
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'tenant': TENANT_ID
}


response = post(url=LOGIN_URI, headers=headers, data=body)
response.raise_for_status()
response_body = response.json()

authorization_token = f"{response_body['token_type']} {response_body['access_token']}"

print(authorization_token)

email_header = {
    'Authorization': authorization_token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

message = {
    'body': {
        'content': 'Outlook Mail Testing Demo',
        'contentType': 'Text'
    },
    'sender': {
        'emailAddress': {
            'address': 'email.address.of.shared.mailbox@active-directory-tenant.tld',
            'name': 'Name of Shared Mailbox'
        }
    },
    'subject': 'Testing email',
    'toRecipients': [
        {
            'emailAddress': {
                'address': 'temprorary.email.address@another-domain.tld',
                'name': 'Name of person to whom email belongs'
            }
        }
    ]
}

email_body = {
    'message': message
}

email_send_response = post(url='https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/1ab4e76f-5f52-44b8-8a72-7d03c05e6ff4/sendMail', headers=email_header, data=json.dumps(email_body))
print(email_send_response)
```

***OUTPUT:***
[image]

Comment: I tried your code by modifying the parameters, and it returns a 403 Access Denied error. Could you tell me which settings I need to modify?

Comment: What kind of application you are trying to create? Did you modified all the parameters?@DarioLurido

Comment: I solved it, it was an issue with API permissions in the application. THX

Comment: Oh. Great to hear that your issue got fixed. :)